# Popup speech buble UIActionSheet on iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uiactionsheet

I am trying to create a small popup menu that looks like a UIActionSheet in my app
This is what I mean:
[image]

I hope I am able to do this in my iPhone app. Is it some kind of modifyed UIActionSheet or is is all custom made?

How can I make something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like a UIPopover, which is an iPad-only API. I've seen various 3rd party libraries that offer popovers for iPhone and iPod touch. I would suggest searching on GitHub or CocoaControls.com for "iPhone popover".